# Qual é o motivo de não se criar outras comunidades em Português ou outro idioma?

Tags: debate, area51

Estou fazendo uma proposta no Area51 de comunidade sobre o Arduino para a Língua Portuguesa, em especial Brasileiros, já que é uma grande comunidade que reúne mais de 20.000 (vinte mil membros só no Facebook).

Já recebi alguns feedbacks que o SE não tem aprovado comunidades em outras línguas, mas não consegui saber o motivo oficial.

Há realmente alguma restrição?
Segue a proposta atual da comunidade que estou promovendo:

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Arduino Brasil]

Comment: Não sei seria uma restrição, mas talvez interesse do pessoal da SE em criar uma nova comunidade em outras línguas.

Comment: O principal receio deles é que uma nova comunidade em português tire usuários ou até comprometa o futuro do [pt.so]. Mas já ouvi dizer que essa opinião não é unânime nem dentro da própria Stack Exchange. Eu seguiria com a proposta para ver no que dá, mas tenha sempre em mente que ela pode acabar fechada e excluída como aconteceu com a do Super User em Português.

Comment: Para mais detalhes, veja o debate em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2543/super-user-em-português-por-que-o-projeto-foi-fechado

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu acho que a unica forma de se constatar que se terá sucesso em algo desta natureza é tentando.

Estou conviquito que a Comunidade que estou propondo irá sem duvida contribuir com o crescimento do SOpt e não dividir.

Comment: Eu acho meio chato a SE estar barrando a criação de sites da rede em outras linguas... Também não vejo essa possibilidade de divisão do pessoal da comunidade.... São assuntos tratados em cada site que são muito diferentes um do outro... E por serem diferentes, vai ter muita gente disposta a participar... E também a necessidade de "doar" a quantidade de usuários de um site para o outro como foi exposto lá....

Comment: Vejo que a SE quer dificultar ao máximo a criação de outros sites por falta de organização deles mesmos..

Comment: @bfavaretto, estou lendo o link sugerido, e realmente contribui muito com minha dúvida.

Comment: abri esta discussão na comunidade Arduino em Inglês: http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/q/1265/3570

Comment: Até que tenhamos uma luz no fim do túnel sobre a possibilidade de termos ou não uma comunidade, eu acredito piamente que teremos, então crie um chat geral para que o pessoal possa e esquentando lugar e não quer se envolver com questões administrativas, políticas e econômicas do SOpt:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24239/arduino-brasil-bate-papo-e-tira-duvidas