# Ampliando o Escopo do Stack Overflow PT?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

O Arduino e outros computadores e placas para prototipação tem crescido muito e estão sem dúvida na mão de uma porcentagem muito grande de programadores, porém é um tema muito vasto que vai da programação a eletrônica, passando por novos formatos de hardwares.

Não temos um site em português que os mesmos moldes do Stack Overflow para tratarmos nossas dúvidas e participarmos com tal motivação.

Já [tentei criar novas comunidades para o nosso idioma](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3817/3117), português, porém a administração do SE sempre fecha as propostas informando não haver no momento a possibilidade de dar prosseguimento já que não há recursos humanos e técnicos necessários para manutenção das mesmas.

[image: imagem da proposta fechada]

Seria possível abrir exceções e estender os temas relacionados a Arduino para abrigar dúvidas básicas relativas a Hardware e Eletrônica? Até que possamos ter novas comunidades sejam com temas definidos como "Embarcados", "Arduino" ou "Engenharia Eletrônica"?

Comment: Esse é um debate importante. Não tenho opinião 100% formada a respeito, vejo vantagens e desvantagens.

Comment: Delfino, para continuar estimulando a discussão, creio que seria interessante você adicionar na sua pergunta original as informações que o @Math postou como comentário na minha resposta (de que a rede SE não está muito receptiva para as propostas de sites específicos em português, e que o site que você já propôs foi fechado). Esse tipo de informação é relevante no sentido de que pode mudar o foco da discussão: se pode concordar facilmente que os assuntos são importantes, mas é necessário verificar qual é o impacto de ampliar o escopo deste site para incluí-los.

Comment: Vou deixar esta outra pergunta como sendo um adendo a esta: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3989/8039

Comment: @brasofilo a pagina da proposta no A51 foi removida, esse link parece irrelevante agora, não?

Comment: @Math, na verdade, não tinha conferido se o link funcionava... e parece que nenhum cache ainda tem ele (google, archive.org). Talvez deixá-lo por razões históricas? Ou talvez para sinalizar como é que as propostas morrem no A51?

Comment: @brasofilo que tal assim?

Comment: @Math, good! O negócio agora é o dead link pro PNG da Area51 lá naquela pergunta :P

Comment: @brasofilo hahaha.. acho melhor deixar lá por razões históricas

Comment: @Math, kkkk, oroboros!

Answer (score 13):

Acho que a discussão hardware/eletrônica x programação é a mesma a respeito de matemática x programação. As vezes as perguntas são importantes pra comunidade (leia-se, para mais do que meia dúzia de participantes) e o assunto requer alguma exploração além da mera programação.

Mas o assunto pode ou não estar no escopo, dependendo de como é explorado. Considere um exemplo matemático (mais fácil pra eu formular, já que não conheço praticamente nada de eletrônica). Alguém poderia vir aqui e perguntar "Como se calcula o determinante de uma matriz de ordem X?". Essa pergunta, formulada desse jeito, não é do escopo. Mas o AP pode saber como se calcula o determinante de fato, só não saber como fazê-lo usando a linguagem Y. Por isso, muita gente (eu incluso) comenta perguntando se o AP está usando alguma linguagem, se já fez alguma coisa, se está tendo algum resultado diferente do esperado.

As vezes o AP também não sabe a matemática por trás do assunto, mas ainda assim precisa/deseja fazer a implementação computacional. Nesse caso, é *o meu* entendimento que alguma ajuda pode fazer parte do escopo, mesmo requerendo na resposta alguma explicação teórica/matemática para auxiliar à compreensão.

Sendo assim, a minha conclusão é que esse tipo de coisa tem que ser analisada com base em perguntas de exemplo. O que eu sugiro pra você, que parece ser alguém interessado no assunto, é ficar de olho em perguntas do tipo (até mesmo "testar" a comunidade, postando algumas que julgar bacanas). As vezes elas são justas segundo algum argumento como os que eu dei, e a comunidade discorda. Podem chover votos para fechar muito rapidamente. Mas, mesmo que ninguém vote pra encerrar, você mesmo pode vir até aqui e abrir um novo questionamento a respeito da pertinência daquela pergunta em especial (até mesmo linkando esta sua primeira pergunta sobre o assunto). Com exemplos de perguntas, certamente vai ser mais fácil a nossa própria decisão a respeito do assunto ser ou não ser válido/aceitável. :)

Comment: Faz sentido isso, mas eu andei imaginando dois casos limítrofes (se não totalmente off-topic) que não envolvem desenvolvimento de software: perguntas sobre criação de circuitos (por exemplo: "como precisa ser o meu circuito para acender um led ao pressionar um botão, com Arduino"), e dúvidas teóricas sobre eletrônica ("o que faz um transístor?", "como funciona a lei de Ohm" etc).

Comment: Eu até enxergo essa nebulosidade de fronteira no primeiro cenário, porque alguém poderia argumentar que ele envolve lógica. Nos demais, honestamente, não (i.e. parecem fortemente off-topic). :) Mas, reforço que o conteúdo de uma pergunta real ajudaria muito nessa interpretação. Alguém poderia simplesmente fazer a pergunta "Como funcionam leds?". Mas, poderia usar "Como funciona um led?" no título e no corpo da pergunta ter algo como "Fiz esse código para acender um led e não funciona porque o led pisca e apaga. Como faço pra deixar aceso? Como funciona um led?". São contextos bem distintos.

Comment: Eu concordo com você, não fui muito claro. O primeiro caso é isso mesmo, pode-se argumentar que construir um circuito é muito semelhante a construir um software, em termos de lógica e fluxo de informação. O segundo caso é mesmo fortemente off-topic, e eu citei pois acho que a falta disso iria comprometer o surgimento de bons conteúdos nas tags em questão. Por exemplo, se alguém posta uma dúvida em cuja origem está o desconhecimento do funcionamento básico de algum conceito ou componente, não seria possível fechar como duplicata de uma pergunta canônica sobre isso (porque a pergunta seria off).

Comment: Ah, ok. :) Boa colocação sobre a impossibilidade de haver perguntas canônicas porque elas seriam, em sua natureza, off-topic. Pra mim é mais um argumento de que é bom tratar casos de perguntas de exemplo. Até para ter alguma "jurisprudência" pra discussões futuras.

Comment: Antes de tudo, excelente resposta! @bfavaretto Sua preocupação faz sentido, mas acho que existe uma diferença muito grande entre "pergunta canônica" e "resposta canônica". [Essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/9835), por exemplo, não pediu nada sobre arquitetura de processadores, mas a resposta aceita tocou no assunto de maneira não trivial, e se tornou um repositório canônico, mesmo sem ser off-topic. É sempre prerrogativa das respostas (e respondedores) decidir o *quanto* deve ou precisa ser explicado.

Comment: Concordo com o @Gabe, excelente resposta. Parece-me que é mesmo esse o caminho que devemos seguir. Casos limítrofes que criem divergências devem ser discutidos e analisados pela comunidade.

Comment: Votei +1 pelo esforço da resposta, irei analisar os comentários e votarei naqueles que julgam que somam de forma positiva, ou mesmo contra argumentando, mais tarde faço um comentário com base em todos os comentários, mas adianto que minha posição é oposta a esta questão, já que o problema não é a eletrônica na programação, mas a abertura do site em relação a eletrônica devido ao movimento que já está consolidado de prototipação, eu acho válido que a moderação e política do SOPT se abra ao tema para atender este nicho que pode usufruir e futuramente quando possível ter um site especializado.

Comment: Já que há tamanho movimento talvez o mais correto seja você propor uma comunidade sobre eletrônica em português no [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). O argumento "não tem em português" é complicado de ser usado pra justificar algo, porque abriria muito o leque de um site. Por exemplo, nós também não temos em português sites só sobre matemática como o [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/) ou só sobre cerveja como o [Beer](http://beer.stackexchange.com/), mas isso não quer dizer que seria efetivamente útil (e prático) permitir livremente perguntas sobre tais assuntos em um só site.

Comment: E só pra constar, já há em inglês os sites [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) e [Arduino](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/). Eles podem ser usados como inspiração pra a proposição de um em português.

Comment: Achei que seu link de dois comentários antes apontava pro meu perfil, mas me enganei

Comment: Na verdade ele já fez o que você sugeriu, mas a proposta foi fechada. Veja aqui: [Qual é o motivo de não se criar outras comunidades em Português ou outro idioma?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3817/3117) E já que falou sobre o Math, veja também esse link: [Mathematics em Português](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3867/3117)

Comment: Ah, eu não sabia. Obrigado pela informação @Math.

Comment: Seria possível/desejável criar um site mais abrangente no stackexchange que possa receber mais questões? Não sei se é boa ideia alterar o âmbito/escopo do SOpt, mas penso que teria algum interesse ver no SO/SE, pelo menos, perguntas de Informática e de Electrónica em português que não se enquadram no SOpt. Por exemplo, como o unix.SE.com.

Comment: @njsg Pelo que eu entendi das discussões nos links que o Math postou, tá mais fácil mesmo ampliar o escopo do SOPT do que criar qualquer outro site no idioma. Essa ampliação até poderia aumentar o uso do site, mas eu tenho minhas dúvidas se seria interessante pra organização e qualidade do conteúdo.

Comment: Bem, minha intenção na ampliação do contexto  seja algo temporário, e que seja a temas que orbitam o cenário principal do SOpt, no caso a eletrônica hoje se tornou intima da programação com a disseminação e popularização de microcontroladores no mercado, quando tais tópicos começarem a sufocar o SOpt, não tenho dúvida que será um excelente argumento para abertura de novas comunidades. Neste caso o movimento no site justificará o investimento em propaganda e quem sabe equipe para outras iniciativas.

Comment: Entendo. Mas não existe uma grande dificuldade a respeito do que devemos considerar como "orbitam o cenário principal do SOpt"? Vai ter muita coisa além de Arduino, Eletrônica e Matemática. Por exemplo, volta e meia temos perguntas sobre legislação e no passado tivemos até perguntas sobre comportamento no escritório. Nesse caso, tudo isso deveria ser *também* aceito temporariamente (até por uma questão de igualdade)? Eu também me entristeço com o fechamento de propostas legais de sites em Pt, mas realmente tenho receios sobre uma permissão temporária dessas.